# No window bar SDL C++ application

Tags: c++, eclipse, excel, graphics, sdl

Usually when somebody opens a program, like eclipse, or word, or excel, before the program start a small little window without window bar is shown (where the quit button is for example).

How I do it in C++ with SDL?  I know how to make an standard window but not how to make a window without window bar

Comment: Side Bar, its called a splash-loader, if I understand the window you're referring to, and the title/caption bar is what I think you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For SDL 1.x, pass [`SDL_NOFRAME`](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlsetvideomode.html) in the flags argument of [`SDL_SetVideoMode`](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlsetvideomode.html).

```
SDL_Surface * window = SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, bpp, flags | SDL_NOFRAME);
```

For SDL 2.x, use [`SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.fcg/SDL_WindowFlags) in the flags argument of [`SDL_CreateWindow`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.fcg/SDL_CreateWindow).

```
SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, x, y, width, height, flags | SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS);
```

Comment: +1 Not knowing SDL, I'm curious, does it support a framed window that does *not* have a caption in the default handler, or must you owner-draw it? just wondering.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I'm not sure what you mean by "caption in the default handler".  Do you mean the title at the top?

Comment: Yes, that was what I was referring to. In Windows DefWindowProc takes care of all the non-client drawing for you (which was what I meant by the default handler). Can you setup a SDL window similarly by style-flags or some such to simply omit the caption, but retain the border frame?

Comment: @WhozCraig: Not that I'm aware of. But you can pass an empty string. Wouldn't that have the same effect or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: That would still yield a caption bar in WinAPI, but it would be blank. By removing the WS_CAPTION bit from the dwStyle creation bits using WinAPI you can keep your sizing borders, framing etc, but there just is no caption bar (even if you set the title to a non-blank string, it will simply be ignored during rendering). I think you understand though. SDL has seemed like an interesting windowing kit to me for awhile, was thinking about taking it up on some of our projects here, and was just curious.

Comment: Nope, I didn't understand, but it occured to me what you probably meant as you were writing that.  Basically, you want the border on the top to be thin like the bottom and the sides, so there wouldn't even be enough room for the title.  If that's the case then I am not aware of a way to do that. But I'm not really an expert in the matter.

Comment: You definitely understand now. Your description was spot-on. ok. thanks for the info, sir.